# Linking a .DLL in Visual Basic Class Projekt not working. FileNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, import, dll, dllimport

i want to build a DLL which imports another DLL in a fixed directory. The DLL which i want to import works with some relative paths which i cant modify and i dont have any insight in this "external" DLL. I just got the information that it is compiled for 32bit.

For my DLL which is an Visual Basic Class Library (working with Visual Studio 2022 Target Framework .NET Target Framework 4.62.) it is important to not copy any parts of the external dll into my project folder because it is just working for the "fixed" directory where it lays right now..

Thanks for you help

So i tried the following steps so far:

- I added the external .DLL via Add existing element -> Add as link -> Properties set to "Content" + "Not Copying)
- I then realized that "Adding as Link" is not enough to now define the "Import ExampleDLL"
- So is also tried to find the DLL in the Referral Manager to add it as Reference.
- It was not there initially so i went to project properties and added the Referral Path where the external DLL lays right now.
- Then i could choose the .DLL in the Referral Manager under Assembly and choose it.
- I deselected local copy in the properties of the Reference.
- Namespace for Imports was now found and i could build the project.

Still i get the FileNotFoundException:

> FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "ExampleDLL,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" oder eine
> Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
> angegebene Datei nicht finden.

I also tried to add the path of the DLL inn the app.config via:

```
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="test"                                                
                          culture="neutral"
                          publicKeyToken="e33b67d3bb5581e4"/>
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" 
                  href="FILE:///C:/Applications/xxx/bi/ExampleDLL.dll"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

but i didnt get this working for now either.

Could somebody explain me the right way of importing a DLL without changing its original directories and without copying anything of the DLL. I can't look into the DLL so i cant really tell what is missing right now.

Here i add the Log from the Assembly Fusion Log (sorry for german)

```
*** Protokolleintrag für Assembly-Binder  (12.09.2023 @ 11:20:29) ***

Fehler bei diesem Vorgang.
Ergebnis der Bindung: hr = 0x80070002. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

Der Assemblymanager wurde geladen aus:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Als EXE-Datei ausgeführt.  C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\bin\x86\Debug\xxx.exe
--- Ein detailliertes Fehlerprotokoll folgt. 

=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: DisplayName = ExampleDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/bin/x86/Debug/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: DynamicBase = NULL
LOG: CacheBase = NULL
LOG: AppName = xxx.exe
Aufruf von Assembly : xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\bin\x86\Debug\xxx.exe.Config
LOG: Die Hostkonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: 
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Die Richtlinie wird derzeit nicht auf den Verweis angewendet (private, benutzerdefinierte, teilweise oder pfadbasierte Assemblybindung)
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/bin/x86/Debug/ExampleDLL.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/bin/x86/Debug/ExampleDLL/ExampleDLL.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/bin/x86/Debug/ExampleDLL.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/bin/x86/Debug/ExampleDLL/ExampleDLL.EXE.
LOG: Fehler bei allen Such-URLs.
```

So it is basically looking in the Project bin/Debug still and of course its not finding anything.
the correct Search URL would be:

```
URL file:///C:/Applications/xxx/bi/ExampleDLL.dll
```

In my App the exception appears at this line:

```
Public Module Testmodule
    Public WithEvents DLLTest As New ExampleDLL.M1
```

So the Sub M1 which is defined in the DLL is recognized. But the throw occurs here when i start debugging.

Comment: I was trying some more things and two question came up:

For the <codeBase> in the app.config i read on MSDN that:
Note   Referenced assemblies outside the application's root directory must have strong names and must either be installed in the global assembly cache or specified using the <codebase> element.

Is this correct as it is ? That means i have to strong name the external DLL first ?

Furthermore i tried the "Assembly Binding Log" and i catched more detailed error messages. Basically it still looked in the bin/Debug of my project. So i setup my <codeBase> wrong ?

Comment: Is the problem now that i didn't correctly setup my "Search URL" (any idea why?) or that the external DLL is not strong named. 
To me it looks that it has more to do with the search DLL, simply because it is just looking in bin/Debug folder of the project ?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing directly with DllImport.

```
<DllImport("C:\Applications\xxx\bi\ExampleDLL.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function SomeFunction() As Integer

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. In my case it is not working because i am working within a Module. There it says DLLImportAttribute is not guilty for this declaration type. Switching to Shared Functions is not an option right now for me.

Comment: Try creating a Class within your Module and define your imported methods within that class, then use the Class to call the imported functions.

Answer (score 0):

An option to make this work is to include the reference as normal in your project, but select for it to not be copied to the output on build.

Then, somewhere in your program, provide a handler for `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` for the current domain (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain`).  In the handler, you can try to load from the fixed folder using e.g. `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

The `AssemblyResolve` event handler takes the assembly name as a string, but you may want to convert it into an `AssemblyName` to parse out the name, version, and (if applicable) public key token.